# HP D2700 configuration

Tags: storage, zfs, hp-smart-array, sas

I have a HP D2700 connected to a dl360G7 with a p812 controller using one SAS cable.
The storage enclosure houses 23 SAS 450GB disks with one spare for a raid6 array.
It serves as an nfs datastore for 2 esxi servers.

In order to maximize prerfomance what would the best configuration?
Is my cabling correct ? Shouldn't i use 2 SAS cables to maximize perfomance and / or get redundancy?

I have been reading on noumerous posts and i am between :

1) ditch the p812 and get an HP HBA H220 controller and zfs with maybe a couple of ssd disks for cache(l2arc).

2) replace the dl360g7 with an spare hp dl360e  and a p822 card.I would prefer to avoid it as the dl360e has better perfomance than the g7 as esxi host.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to "maximize the performance" of? What metrics are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the [ZFS high availability guide](https://github.com/ewwhite/zfs-ha/wiki) that describes the use of low-cost HP StorageWorks D2700 disk enclosures.

See: https://github.com/ewwhite/zfs-ha/wiki

As far as your setup, we'll want more details about your goals and expectations.

- What operating system is in place right now?
- It looks like you only have one storage server.
- Dual-ported/dual-path disk cabling won't have an appreciable impact on what you're doing.
- How are you connecting everything to the VMware ESXi hosts?
- What is the networking setup?
- Are you asking whether to use ZFS or not?

Comment: hello and thanks for your reply,

You guide is very precise, I have come across it many times.


I am using centos 7.4 and yes, its a single storage server.The file system for the exported datastore is XFS.

The esxi hosts are connected through 1 gb links ( 1 for management and 1 for storage each).
The server uses 2 x 1 gb ethernet bonded.
I am planning to upgrade the entire network to 10gb.


the hosts run about 10-15 vms that run MySQL databases with 3-4 million rows each (they take a performance hit that’s why i am looking for ways to improve disk performance).

Comment: Bottom line is, i am asking if zfs would be used to speed up my datastore speed up for my scenario.

I have a small budget for ssd and from what i read if i understand it correctly zfs with most problably be a better choice that invest in hp raid controllers with ssd support.

Comment: "Speed up" how? Can you identify what or if you even have a performance issue?

Comment: I notice many times on peak hours, the iowait on the storage server increases.And so goes on in the virtual machines. I havent run any benchmarks, i dont know even how to benchmark it correctly as i guess simple file transfer with dd or equivelant wont tell me much.